# OpenACC/PGI/C++: в чем писать код

Tags: c++, parallel

Хочу распараллелить некоторые алгоритмы с использованием стандарта OpenACC. 
Скачал фришный компилятор PGI.

Только не понимаю, где/в чем именно писать нужно код (не в терминале компилятора же...)? Может, существует какая-то особая среда разработки?

Comment: В смысле в чем? В редакторе...

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch ну допустим. а запускать в терминале?

Comment: что запускать? редактор? комилятор? программу?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch программу

Comment: как хотите так и запускайте, можете и в терминале, можете через IDE (если пользуетесь конечно)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch в какой IDE? Студия не поддерживает OpenACC. Я абсолютно не имею понятия о том, как запускать код с директивами этого стандарта, и в этом заключается мой вопрос

Comment: а при чем IDE к стандарту? А если абсолютно не понимаете директив - так откройте блин документацию и почитайте! Ни одна IDE не напишет код за вас. А если и напишет - на кой черт тогда вы нужны будете?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch вы не понимаете. давайте приведу пример: параллелить C++ алгоритмы можно на OpenMP, подключая его к Visual Studio.
Но в моем случае с OpenACC, мне не понятно, где код писать и где его исполнять

Comment: нет, это вы абсолютно не понимаете базовое устройство языка и процесса сборки программы. Вы не понимаете даже то, что библиотеки подключаются к программе, а не к IDE. Так что почитайте, пожалуйста, про препроцессор, транслятор, компилятор и линковщик